# Best way to insert multiple dates to a row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a form to book ads for multiple dates, which are selected by using a calendar in the form and then posted in JSON format. An example would be:

```
[20110915, [20110918, 20110925], 20110926, 20110927]
```

but I am having a problem storing this json string for each ad.

1. *How would you recommend storing this dates with a relation to the ad?*
2. *How to select an ad using one of its dates.*

I don't want to store each date separately in different table (which makes db bulky).

Comment: Is this a question about database structure or about PHP?

Comment: Bulky db is better than using a wildcard search

Answer (score 0):

> How would you recommend storing this dates with a relation to the ad?

You should store them in a relationship table, which will have the id of the ad and the date of the booking.

#### ad_bookings

```
ad_id | booking_date
```

The `PRIMARY KEY` would be the compound `(ad_id, booking_date)`.

Sample data would be:

```
ad_id        | booking_date
---------------------------
1            | 2011-09-15
1            | 2011-09-18
1            | 2011-09-19
1            | 2011-09-20
1            | 2011-09-26
2            | 2011-09-27
2            | 2011-09-30
```

---

> How to select an ad using one of its dates.

```
    SELECT *
      FROM ads a
INNER JOIN ad_bookings ab
        ON a.ad_id = ab.ad_id
       AND ab.booking_date = '2011-09-30'
```

Comment: @Vaibhav Gupta: If you are already doing it, then don't look any further. Making it "table bulky" does not make it bad solution compared to the nightmare of inserting, updating, and selecting into/from an unnormalized table schema.